# How to center a string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm making a batch game, and i want the player write the name of your character, and that name appears on the screen inside a text box. Like this:

```
@echo off
color 0a
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion 
mode 80,30

set /p nickname=Enter your nickname:
pause
cls
echo.
echo       +------------------+
echo       ¦    %nickname%    ¦  
echo       +------------------+
pause
```

but as the nickname can be any, when the nickname number of letters is different from 10 (number of letters of variable %nickname%) the right bar  of the text box is pushed or pulled. So when the batch starts looks like this:

```
Enter your nickname: Rob
Press any key to continue...


+------------------+
¦    Rob    ¦  
+------------------+
Press any key to continue...
```

(i use the nickname Rob for example, can be any name)
So how i fix it?? There is something to do with the "|" character does not change your position?

Comment: Should there be a maximum number of characters?

Comment: IMHO the topic title is somewhat confusing. Perhaps something like "How to center a string in batch file" would be clearer...

Comment: @DennisvanGils I do not think about it, maybe 8 is a good  maximum number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set /p nickname=Enter your nickname:
echo.
echo       +------------------+
SET "nick=%nickname%"
:loop1
IF DEFINED nick IF "%nick:~17,1%" neq "" GOTO shownick
SET "nick=%nick% "
IF "%nick:~17,1%" neq "" GOTO shownick
SET "nick= %nick%"
GOTO loop1
:shownick
echo       ^|%nick%^|  
echo       +------------------+
GOTO :EOF
```

Copy the name to another variable (`nick`)

If `nick` is not empty, then if its 18th character exists, go to `shownick`
otherwise, append a space to the end of `nick`
test again for 18th character, if not exist, prepend a space to `nick` and continue until character 18 exists.

Note that the syntax `%nick:~17,1%` means `the`1` character starting at "character 18" where the string starts at "character 0"

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a `for /l loop`? That's what I came up with.

Comment: AAMOI, I believe you are using some variety of WP to produce this batch. It produces an odd character on my display. The `|` is a special character with a specific meaning to `cmd`, so it needs to be `escaped` by being preceded by a caret `^` as shown...

Comment: @DennisvanGils: Really? You believe that writing and deleting a file is easier? Well- we all have our own opinions. Why not, having calculated `strlength`, set "spaces=*a whole bunch of spaces*" then echo `spaces:~-%strlength%` ? And my version centres the name on the line, whereas yours keeps a startic starting position for the name and adjusts the position of the closing pipe. There are many ways to solve this microproblem, as usual. You pays yer money, you takes yer choice...

Comment: First of all, the "wouldn't it be easier" was a genuine question, I didn't call my answer easier. I didn't see that you were adding spaces to the front and the back of the nick to keep it centered, which caused my confusion. I apologise for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different variant of what Magoo came up with:

```
@echo off
color 0a
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion 
mode 80,30

set /p "nickname=Enter your nickname: "
ECHO %nickname%>x&FOR %%? IN (x) DO SET /A strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
set "spaces="
for /l %%a in (%strlength%, 1, 13) do set "spaces=!spaces! "
pause
cls
echo.
echo       +------------------+
echo       ^|    %nickname%%spaces%^|
echo       +------------------+
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Append a bunch of spaces and then strip out as many characters as you want for your fixed field width. I just left the exclamation mark there as a visual indicator for your debugging:

```
set "n=%n%          !"
set n=%n:~0,10%
```

Here's an example usage incorporated into your script. I'm storing in a separate variable since the original value is being modified and you might need it later and also because if the name entered is *longer* than ten characters then it's going to be truncated. The naming scheme is sort of inspired by COBOL although it might prove to become tedious to incorporate the length into the variables name.

```
@echo off
set /p nickname=Enter your nickname:
set "zz10=%nickname%          "
set zz10=%zz10:~0,10%

echo       +------------------+
echo       +    %zz10%    +
echo       +------------------+
```

Since the word "nickname" plus two percent characters is ten characters wide I'm guessing that might be why you specified a maximum width of ten. While that does make it a little easier to lay out the banner obviously there's no requirement for that.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it?