# How do i center a InputBox In Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm Working on a Batch Game called BatchOS That basically imitates an Actual Operating System. While i was making the Internet Explorer for BatchOS. I Found something that i had to ask for. How do i Center a InputBox in Batch? Like there is no actual Questions about this. I wanted everything centered.

Screenshot:

[The code says that The InputBox is centered but in Command Prompt. It's Not Centered at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6sTp.jpg)

I'm In Windows 11 Btw

Comment: Yes, repro'd on Windows 10. It's not a platform problem.

Comment: What do you mean by Repro'd on Windows 10?

Comment: `Set /p` does not print leading spaces. Echo the spaces first, then use set /p for the prompt.

Comment: Uhhh How? Is it Like                                                                                                     @Echo Off
Echo.. /P input= Input:

Comment: Or a workaround: Print U+200B (zero width space) in front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set /P` command trims leading white-spaces. But there is a nice work-around.

At first, do:

```cmd
for /F %%B in ('prompt $H^& for %%Z in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "_BS=%%B"
```

to gather the back-space character. Then do:

```cmd
set /P INPUT="#%_BS%    Prompt: "
```

to get leading <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> on the console display.

The trick is to begin the prompt text with a character other than a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (like `#`), but then move the cursor back by a back-space (<kbd>⟵</kbd>), so the first of the following <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> overwrites that character, thus deleting it.

Hence the actually printed character sequence is:

> `#` <kbd>⟵</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> `Prompt:` <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

which leads to the displayed text:

> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> `Prompt:` <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Comment: 2 Questions tho. How do you add those Key images things and how did you explain and understand your Own Code?

Comment: 1. Click the [edit] button beneath my answer, then you can see the plain text. 2. I think I can't quite follow, I only can tell I've got some experience with batch scripting…

Comment: Wow you have to Code in Stackoverflow to get Those cool Keyboard buttons?

Comment: This is called *Markdown* and is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)…

Answer (score 1):

It is not centered in the middle because for it to be in the center, you have to write a code which will keep resetting the code every 1 ms and check the location where the center is then center it there.

Comment: Do you know what code does that? Or you know a code doing that but you cant type in it

Comment: I think this question issue should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729834/how-to-center-a-string-in-a-batch-file

Comment: I am trying to find a way to center the InputBox with this Forum but it didn't help.  i can only center Text with it. Not InputBoxes :(

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I found that might help you

```
echo                  URL:
set /p url=
```

but the input will be at the below and not centered.

Comment: It is Below :((

Comment: Wow this Question is really Hard to Solve

Comment: i just read somewhere that `set/p` will ignore if there's space/tab after it, and i think you  can't use `set/p` for this. Maybe find another programming language

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)'s where i read it, the first comment on the first answer

Comment: well i would Switch to a new programming language. If I hadn't Already made as much progress as literally Releasing 2 Versions of My BatchOS Project

Answer (score 1):

ANSII color codes will help you.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set ESC=%%b
)

set /p url=%ESC%[30m------------------%ESC%[0mURL:
```

Comment: I mean if you're going to use ANSI escape sequences, you might as well use `ESC[Y;XH` to actually place the text where you want it.

Comment: You should add the code to produce the escape character (like the technique, aschipfl used)

Comment: ESC[Y;XH? How do i use that?